# UnityException while building toWindows phone 10

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, windows-phone

I used iTextSharp to save some data into pdf files, and when I try to build my aplication for windows phone 10, Unity3d gets an exception.

```
UnityException: Failed to run reference rewriter with command -- target="Temp\StagingArea\itextsharp.dll"
```

Comment: are you sure your iTextSharp reference property 'Copy Local' is set to true?

Comment: it seems like Unity's trying to locate the dll but can't find it. Try a hard-fix: if you have itextsharp.dll in your plugins folder (or anywhere at all) try to paste it in your projectDirectory/Temp/StagingArea/

Comment: or yea, if you have a build setting for that even better...

Comment: where I can find to set 'Copy local true'? yes my dll are in plugins folder,

Comment: projectDirectory is your project directory, I'm using a pseudo name, basically a directory above your Assets folder

Comment: ok, my dll exist in 'projectDirectory/Temp/StagingArea/'

Comment: Error building Player: UnityException: Failed to run reference rewriter with command --target="Temp\StagingArea\itextsharp.dll" --additionalreferences="Temp\StagingArea"

Comment: well I don't know then. probably unity's copying it from plugins folder into temp. try to delete it and re-build

Comment: if this does not work I can't help :/

Comment: yes unity copy from plugins folder to stagingArea, I remove iTextSharp.dll, rebuild, but I get the same error

Comment: what you want to say about build settings @Nika Kasradze

Comment: it seems like iTextSharp is not working on WP8 platform, look at the post for solution: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2013/08/15/how-to-generate-pdf-on-windows-phone-in-vb-or-c/